# Rutas api de laravel no funcionan

Tags: laravel, api, postman

Me puse aprender apis de Laravel y no logró hacer que las rutas funcionen, simplemente dicen que no están

Voy a colocar todos los archivos relevantes del video para que puedan observar en donde se encuentra el error, ya que intenté seguir todo al pie de la letra pero no se si los métodos que el sujeto del video utiliza son anticuados o algo así

Si preguntan, [me estuve guiando de éste video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pc6cgisbKE&t=400s) y trate de copiar y hacer todo exactamente como lo hizo pero el momento en que él usa POSTMAN, la ruta no funciona. Estoy usando Laravel 7.19 y lo instalé mediante composer como se debe, estoy usando vhost de Xammp

Esto es lo que tengo en RouteServiceProvider.php, lo modifique deacuerdo al video de más abajo

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

Las rutas que tengo en api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

//Listar articulos
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');

//Listar articulos solos
Route::get('article/{id}', 'ArticleController@show');

//Crear articulo nuevo
Route::post('articles', 'ArticleController@store');

//Editar articulo
Route::put('articles', 'ArticleController@store');

//Borrar articulo
Route::delete('articles', 'ArticleController@destroy');
```

Esto es lo que tengo en ArticleController, el cual ya tiene un método index que trae artículos de la base de datos, pero éste no puede correr por el error de las rutas

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Article;

use App\Http\Resources\Articles as ArticleResource;


class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //Obtener articulos
        $articles = Article::paginate(15); //Obtiene 15

        //Regresar los articulos como recursos
        return ArticleResource::collection($articles);
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Lo que tengo en Article.php, el modelo de Article no posee datos todavía ya que el del video no le puso datos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Lo que tengo en Resources/Article.php, el cual según el video era necesario para poder traerlos articulos.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Article extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Que tal, puedes compartir la URL a la que estas queriendo ingresar y el mensaje de error que te aparece por favor?

Comment: Como el video dice, estoy probando la url asi http://peoplefinder.test/api/articles. Y me sale "Object not located", el error de Xammp

Comment: Solo una pregunta, tu host virtual ya funciona?

Comment: Si, el host virtual funciona y muestra la pantalla inicial

Comment: te arroja algun otro error?

Comment: No, solo el de Objeto no localizado

Comment: probablemente sean los ssl de tu servidor xampp, modificando tu php.ini y descargando las credenciales en https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daré un ejemplo de como manejo en lo personal `api.php`, y no tiene nada que ver con el video que dejaste o con lo que mostraste.

**1er paso:** Tener un campo `api_token` unico en la tabla usuarios.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('api_token', 100)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
    //otros datos necesarios.
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Este `api_token` sirve para pasar el `middleware auth:api`, puedes generarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
...
$user->api_token=Str::random(60);
```

En lo personal siempre lo cambio cada vez que el usuario realiza un nuevo login.

**2do paso:** utilizamos `api.php` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get("gestion","Api\ApiGestionController@getlista");


Route::group(["middleware"=>"auth:api"],function(){
    Route::get("objeto","Api\ApiObjetoGastoController@index");
    Route::post("objeto","Api\ApiObjetoGastoController@store");
});
```

Existen tres rutas en el ejemplo de las cuales 2 la de `objeto` deben de contener `api_token`, y en `gestion` no es necesario. Ademas en la referencia al controlador `ApiObjetoGastoController` se nota `Api\`, que solo indica la dirección de una carpeta.

**3er paso:** acceder a las rutas, como viste en `RouteServicesProvider.php`, en la funcion `mapApiRoutes` existe el prefijo `api`

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')//esta de aca
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

Por lo cual para acceder a las rutas estos deben de contener `api` como prefijo. EJ:

```
tu_url.com/api/gestion
tu_url.com/api/objeto?api_token={{$user->api_token}}
```

Ambos deben de funcionar correctamente si los controladores están bien.

**4to paso:** retornar valores desde los controladores.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\ObjetoGasto;
class ApiObjetoGastoController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $objetos=ObjetoGasto::with(["clasificador","patron"])->orderBy("nombre","asc")->paginate(100);
        return response()->json(["objetos"=>$objetos],200);
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        $user=$request->user("api");
        $data=new ObjetoGasto($request->all());
        $data->user_id=$user->id;
        $data->estado=true;
        $data->save();
        return response()->json($data->load("clasificador","patron"),200);
    }
}
```

Donde se puede observar la función `index` la cual retorna un `array`, y en la funcion `store` se ve: `$user=$request->user("api");` que es la forma de recuperar el usuario logueado. Esta función retorna un `objeto`.

**Recomendación:**

Los modelos en laravel por lo menos deben de tener la propiedad `$fillable`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class ObjetoGasto extends Model
{
    //esto minimanente
    protected $fillable = ["clasificador_id", "user_id", "patron_id", "estado", "codigo", "nombre", "observacion"];

    public function clasificador()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Clasificador::class);
    }
    public function patron()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patron::class);
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo con respecto al error que te sale, es un error propio de `XAMPP` asi que yo revisaría la configuración de mi virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

En tu Resource Article

definelo de la sieuiente manera

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Article extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return ['data' => $this->collection];
    }
}
```

y une ejemplo de lo que te retornaira sera

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Eladio Schroeder Sr.",
            "email": "therese28@example.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Liliana Mayert",
            "email": "evandervort@example.com",
        }
    ],
    "links":{
        "first": "http://example.com/pagination?page=1",
        "last": "http://example.com/pagination?page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
    "meta":{
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "http://example.com/pagination",
        "per_page": 15,
        "to": 10,
        "total": 10
    }
}
```

---

E intentado y creado una API de un sistema que ya tenia con los mismos elementos Resource y API y no tuve ningun problema con postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el codigo que use mas lo que te puse arriba dentro del resource

```
$users = User::paginate(2);
        return new UserCollection($users);
```

mi archivo api

```
Route::get('users', 'Admin\UsersController@index');
```

> Intente con JSONResource y no tuve ningun problema en obtener los datos

Comment: Lo intente y me sigue diciendo que el objeto no está

Comment: antes del return si haces un `ddd($articles );` que te arroja?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta al llamar las rutas, checa en el minuto 07:21 del video en donde colocan la configuración del servidor. Revisa que lo estás haciendo de forma correcta no olvides quitar los signos de gato #
Si aún no funciona omite ese paso es decir borra todas las líneas que anadiste en este paso o coméntalas con los # e ingresa de la manera convencional con

```
localhost/larticles/articles
```

en este caso es probable que debas agregar una diagonal a tu archivo de routes a cada ruta de esta forma

```
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticleController@index');
```

Ahí por ejemplo la puse antes de articles

Answer (score 0):

Una vez a mi me pasó algo muy similar y estuve tratando de resolverlo como por 2 días y el error era algo muy tonto y nunca supe porque pasaba...

Xampp era mi problema, intenta probar con otro como wamp por ejemplo, mi problema se solucionó solamente con eso, que no encontraba las rutas... así que migré todo el proyecto a Wamp y funcionó sin problemas, luego al subirlo al servidor igualmente funcionó pero con Xampp... y pues imagino que fue porque es un poco mas sencillo... Intenta y nos cuentas

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con mas sencillo?