# Problema con peticiones http desde ionic a laravel

Tags: laravel, angular, api, ionic

desde ya hace un tiempo estoy desarrollando una aplicación en ionic/angular por parte del cliente y un backend en Laravel, he estado trabajando con los 2 proyectos en local desde el navegador ejecutando los siguientes comandos `ionic serve` y `php artisan serve` respectivamente, los cuales no me han dado ningún problema en consultar y mostrar la data. El problema se generó cuando llegue a un punto en que ya necesitaba compilar la aplicación en un dispositivo físico, realizando el comando correspondiente `ionic cordova run android --device --consolelogs -l` me compila pero al hacer la petición para logear me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe señalar que intenté levantar la web laravel mediante ngrok, para descartar que fuese problema de red ya que comente arriba estaban compilandose localmente, teniendo como resultado el mismo error por parte de la aplicación móvil.

Agradecería bastante su ayuda, ya que llevo un buen rato intentando de descifrar el error.

Adjunto la configuración de los archivos en cada uno de los proyectos.

**env.service.ts**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**auth.service.ts**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**api.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AuthController.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes algun middleware que proteja tu ruta `login`. Y otra cosa mas, en futuras preguntas (y si puedes [edita esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/377576/edit)) evitar postear images cuando tengas que mostrar codigo, eso hace mas facil reproducir el error y se te pueda ayudar mas rapido.

Comment: @Shassain tengo implementado laravel passport dentro del proyecto y aparte tengo configurado el cors, aun así, tengo problemas al realizar la solicitud. En cuanto al post lo editaré como corresponde, se agradece el consejo.

Comment: En la funcion `login` tienes `$user=$request->user()`, estoy muy seguro que esa linea codigo no funciona. ya que el user aun no esta en el  `request`. debes de buscar una refactorización de dicho codigo.

Comment: No creo que vaya por ahi el tema, ya que en cada una de las peticiones, ya sea post o get, me arroja el mismo error.

Comment: hace un par de semanas respondi a algo similiar quiza te sirva, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372342/rutas-api-de-laravel-no-funcionan/373529#373529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema solucionado, al final lo corregí agregando mi ip local al archivo **network_security_config.xml** en ionic.