# Permisos en API con laravel permission de spatie

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-permission

Tengo una aplicación con Laravel Permission de Spatie y funciona bien en Web, pero no sé como asignarle a rutas API, necesito completar un formulario desde una aplicación móvil, para ello pienso conectar las dos aplicaciones por medio de esta API, cuando entro en la ruta: miweb.com/api/visits/create  me dice que no tengo persmisos:

Estas son mis rutas:

```
Route::get('visits/create', 'VisitController@create')->name('visits.create')->middleware('permission:visits.create');

Route::post('visits/store', 'VisitController@store')->name('visits.store')->middleware('permission:visits.store');
```

Leí algo de `guards` pero no entiendo mucho y no encuentro información de como implementarlo, no sé si sea la solución, o la única, quizás la mejor?

Para completar el formulario el usuario debe estar logeado en la app móvil, para eso podría usar `Laravel Passport`? o también podría continuar haciendolo como estoy haciendo lo del registro?

Agradezco toda la información uqe puedan darme.

Gracias

Comment: la parte de guardianes solo asignale un predeterminado que tiene laravel que seria `api` asi: `Auth::guard("api")->attempt($credenciales de logueo)` esto al momento de loguear. luego puedes leerte [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372342/rutas-api-de-laravel-no-funcionan/373529#373529)  para complementar, y los middleware deberian de funcionarte sin problemas, el resto de funcionalidad depende te tu imaginacion.

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar y cualquier cosa te vuelvo a escribir.

Comment: Disculpa no he leído aún el tema del enlace, pero con `passport` desde `Postman` he logrado el login, registro y lo demás, con `passport` también podría hacer el registro de los otros datos? o está limitado solo al sistema de logín?

Comment: Pues passport es una alternativa lo que sucede es que me gusta hacerlo de forma manual.

Comment: estoy tratando de hacerlo manual, al menos para el registro del formulario la del login está funcionando bien con passport. Así aprendo, pero estoy perdido :)

Comment: Creo saber porque no me deja acceder, me acabo de dar cuenta (soy nuevo con las API) que la sesiones no se permiten en la API, quería hacer uso de `auth()->id();` y no pude, ahora eso no está relacionado con los permiso? se me complicó ahora porque el formulario debe llevar el `id` del usuario

Comment: Ya veo para que es el token de inicio de sesión

Comment: el acceso  al usuario logueado se hace con `$request->user("api")` en el post que te envie indica como hacer todo el proceso.